# Ember, find model by name with spaces

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use a dynamic segment different than id in Ember:

```
App.MunicipalityDetailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    serialize : function(municipality, params){
        return {
            shortName : municipality.get("shortName"),
        };
    },
    model: function(params) {

        return this.get('store').find('municipality', {shortNameEq_or: [params.shortName]});
    }
});
```

The thing is that shortName contains spaces, for example when shortName = "aaa bb"

My Server is answering correctly to /municipalities?shortNameEq_or[]=aaa%20bb,

Ember data is sending a request to /municipalities?nomeCortoEq_or%5B%5D=aaa+bb

I tried to encodeURI like this:

```
    model: function(params) {
        var encoded = encodeURI(params.shortName);
        return this.get('store').find('municipality', {shortNameEq_or: [encoded]});
    }
```

but the result is that Ember data is asking for /municipalities?nomeCortoEq_or%5B%5D=aaa%2520bb     (i guess it's encoding the "%" to "%25")

How can I solve this?